# React js download a file located in another folder

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, apk

I'm currently working on a web/mobile project. I'm implementing a download button to download the mobile client.
I'm using Docker images and docker compose to deploy the project, I have an image to build the apk with flutter and an image to build and run the front web.

**Here is the docker-compose file**

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  client_mobile:
    build: ./flutter
    volumes:
      - apk-volume:/app/client
  web:
    build: ./front-web
    env_file:
      - ./front-web/.env
    ports:
      - "8081:3000"
    depends_on:
      - client_mobile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - apk-volume:/app/client

volumes:
  apk-volume:
```

**Here is the flutter Dockerfile**

```
FROM androidsdk/android-30

# Install flutter
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y bash git unzip wget
RUN apt-get clean
WORKDIR /
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
ENV PATH "$PATH:/flutter/bin"
ENV FLUTTER_PATH /flutter/
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter precache

# Install gradle
RUN wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
RUN mkdir /opt/gradle
RUN unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
ENV PATH "$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-7.3.3/bin"
RUN rm gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip

RUN mkdir -p /app/android
RUN echo "sdk.dir=$ANDROID_SDK" >> /app/android/local.properties
RUN echo "flutter.sdk=$FLUTTER_PATH" >> /app/android/local.properties
RUN echo "flutter.buildMode=debug" >> /app/android/local.properties
RUN echo "flutter.versionName=1.0.0" >> /app/android/local.properties
RUN echo "flutter.versionCode=1" >> /app/android/local.properties

WORKDIR /app/android
COPY ./ /app/

RUN gradle --refresh-dependencies
RUN flutter build apk --release

CMD mv ../build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk /app/client/app-release.apk
```

**Here is the docker file of the react**

```
FROM node AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN cd /usr/src/app; npm install -g npm@latest; npm install

COPY ./  /usr/src/app/

RUN cd /usr/src/app; npm run build

FROM builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/src/app/build

RUN npm install -g serve

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-l", "3000"]
```

And here is the way i'm downloading the apk file

```js
<a href='/app/client/area_mobile.apk' download style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
  <div className='userPanel__sideBar__rows__row'>
    <div style={{marginRight: "5%", marginTop: "2%"}}>
      <DownloadIcon />
    </div>
    <p>Download Mobile</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

When I click it download a file but it's named `index.html` and contain the equivalent of the actual page i'm in.

Do you know how to deal with this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i've found a way, it's to directly put the .apk in the build file after building the app.